# align-item:center is centering only the first element

Tags: html, css

I applied the `align-item:center` property on nav elements but it is centering only the first div while the second element which is a list is not centered. Please give me a solution and reason why it is happening

```css
body {
  background-color: cadetblue ! important;
  `enter code here`
}

#firstNav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

ul li a:hover,
ul li a:active {
  color: aqua;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="firstNav">
  <div id="logo">Jobee.pk</div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hrings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sotions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Jobee Cares</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code you provided. The elements are centered just fine.

Answer (score -2):

```
<nav id="firstNav">
    <div id="logo">Jobee.pk</div>
   
    <ul class="inner-list">
        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hrings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sotions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jobee Cares</a></li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.inner-list {
  display: "flex";
  align-items: "center";
 }
```

That's the way flexbox works, it acts only on direct children of the parent element. To have the elements of the inner `ul` centered as well, you have to apply flex center styles to it as well.

Comment: The `<ul>` is only as high as the content. That's why it works without your code. If you check the OP's code, it centers just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply But I have tried it.It didn't work